# Cubism.js: Ruler doesn't follow the cursor exactly (not on the right location)

Tags: cubism.js

My problem is that the ruler doesn't exactly land on the cursor as in the screenshot and I'm not sure where to start looking in order to fix it.

[image]

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The positioning of the ruler is `absolute` to the div it's contained within. Therefore, you need to ensure that your div is free from any other styling that may affect this.

For example, using boostrap I had this issue when my horizon graph was within a grid array: 
[image: go away silly offset]

Changing my cubism graph div from:

`<div id="graph"></div>`
to

`<div id="graph" style="position:relative" ></div>`

The ruler then moved to the right position, without effecting the other styles on the page

[image: horray, all fixed]

Reference issue from cubism's github page: https://github.com/square/cubism/issues/18